# Question about linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

So suppose a linear transformation U maps a vector space into itself. Is the rank of U necessarily equal to the rank of its transpose? I know the transpose maps the dual space the same dual space, but I'm not sure how to compute the rank in that case.

Answer (score 1):

At the first you must be show that The annihilator of the range of $U$ is the nullspace of its transpose, then you can conclude the range of $U$ is the annihilator of the nullspace of its transpose. Now we now that the dim of $U$ is equal with dim of its dual, and with the above facts and so that the rank of nullspace addition to rank of range of a linear map is equal to $dim (U)$, similarly dim dual of $U$, you can get that the rank of $U$ is equal to rank of its transpose. 
for more details, you can see the following book in chap 3 and page 27.
Linear Algebra and Its Applications, Peter Lax

Comment: does this hold for infinite dimension vector spaces as well

Comment: I don't know, I think to be true, but this way that I describe don't work.